# Passing a file reference as a function parameter

Tags: php, file-io

I'd like to pass a file reference as a function parameter.  I'm not sure how this works in php, but in js it seems to be fine as long as the variable is defined globally.  Obviously this isn't js, but I'm unsure of how to alter my code to work this out.

In the beginning of my file, I define something like:

```
$myfileref = fopen('../some/path.txt', 'w');

function writeHeader($fileref){
  fwrite($fileref, 'some text here\n');
}
```

Then I'd like to call it like:

```
writeHeader($myfileref);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$outfile = fopen('outfile.txt', 'w');
$path = '.';

$one_html = fopen('../write_dir/one.html', 'w');
if(!is_resource($one_html)){
    die("fopen failed");
}
$two_html = fopen('../write_dir/two.html', 'w');
if(!is_resource($two_html)){
    die("fopen failed");
}
$three_html = fopen('../write_dir/three.html', 'w');
if(!is_resource($three_html)){
    die("fopen failed");
}

function searchFiles($dir){
    $outpath = getcwd() . '/../write_dir/';
    $in_dir = 'none';
    $f_one = $f_two = $f_three = false;
    $thisdir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($thisdir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    global $one_html, $two_html, $three_html;

    foreach($files as $object){
        if($object->isDir()){
            if(strpos($object->getPathname(), 'one') == true){
                if(!$f_one){
                    echo "in one \n";
                    fileHeader($one_html);
                    $f_one = true;
                }
                $in_dir = 'one';
            }
            else if(strpos($object->getPathname(), 'two') == true){
                if(!$f_two){
                    echo "in two \n";
                    fileHeader($two_html);
                    $f_two = true;
                }
                $in_dir = 'two';
            }else if(strpos($object->getPathname(), 'three') == true){
                if(!$f_three){
                    echo "in three  \n";
                    fileHeader($three_html);
                    $f_three = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function fileHeader($fileref){
    fwrite($fileref, "<table border=\"1\">\n");
    fwrite($fileref, '<tr bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\">\n');
    fwrite($fileref, '<th>name</th>');
    fwrite($fileref, '<th>description</th>');
    fwrite($fileref, '<th>authors</th>');
    fwrite($fileref, '<th>version</th>');
    fwrite($fileref, '</tr>');
}

searchFiles('.');

?>
```

Comment: Your code should work as written, what errors are you getting?

Comment: This will work fine for you, with the exception of `\n` not being escape properly (you should be using double quotes instead of single if you want `\n` to be replaced with a line break).

Comment: might be worth passing by reference, by including an `&` before $fileref in your function declaration.

Comment: I would try to add "&" to the filref parameter in function declaration: `function writeHeader(&$fileref)`

Comment: @hexblot: It is not worth passing by reference. Why should it anyway? And please do not irritate users that are new to PHP with such superfluous and shady suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no magic behind passing file descriptors (resources) to a function in PHP. They will be handled just as regular parameters.

The following example will work as is. (Like yours)

```
<?php

// define your function
function write($fd, $message) {
    fwrite($fd, $message);
}

// open a file
$fd = fopen('/tmp/a.txt', 'w');

// make sure that opening succeeded
if(!is_resource($fd)) {
    die('fopen failed');
}

// write to the file
write($fd, 'hello world');

// close the file
fclose($fd);
```

---

**Update** after seeing the original code:

You just missed to pass those file descriptors as params to the function `searchFiles`. So they aren't available in the scope of `searchFiles()`. Please refer to the manual page [Variable Scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Change the function declaration to:

```
function searchFiles($dir, $one_html, $two_html, $three_html){
```

And pass those values to the function when you call it:

```
searchFiles('.', $one_html, $two_html, $three_html);
```

I hope you understand what you've doing wrong.

Comment: I get a warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /path/to/myfile.php

Comment: then `fopen` failed. Make **sure** that you choose a file name that you can write to

Comment: i am able to use a variable reference without an issue.  The issue is that I cannot pass the resource reference to my function.

Comment: Have you executed my updated example? (Just the example, nothing more or less!) .. Do you use apache or cli?

Comment: Ah, OK.  So, your example works and I can verify that (CLI).  But I am not able to call this within *another* function, as the context has changed and the variable reference is undefined.  So, I take it that I need to use a global reference, somehow?

Comment: No, you have just a bug somewhere in your code. Would like you fix it, but need to see the *original* code

Comment: I updated my question to include the original.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see anything wrong with the above code ... must my guess is

```
writeHeader($myfileref);                     <-- -you are calling this
$myfileref = fopen('log.txt', 'w');          <-- -- Before tHis 

function writeHeader($fileref){
  fwrite($fileref, 'some text here\n');
}
```

Switch the position and it should work or just use `SplFileObject` that way you can `easily force type to your function` Example :

```
$file = new SplFileObject("log.txt", "w");
if (! $file->isWritable())
    throw new Exception("I can't write to this");

writeHeader($file);


function writeHeader(SplFileObject $file) {
    $file->fwrite("The 1st Header\r\n");
    $file->fwrite("The 2nd Header\r\n");
    $file->fwrite("The 3rd Header\r\n");
}
```

Comment: `that way you can easily force type to your function`. Ok, now I see. Another good answer! ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

PHP does pass-by-value for most things, so you need to force pass-by-reference:

```
function writeHeader(&$myfileref) {
                     ^--- 
 ...
}
```

so that the myfileref inside writeHeader() is a reference to the "real" file handle outside the function.

Comment: This would have no effect.